# Firebase OTP authentication:token verification API

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

As far as I know firebase Otp verification works on  the following way.

1)On each platforms firebase provides a custom UI for sending and reading OTP.

2)After successful Otp verification firebase returns user data along with a token.

My question is there any way  to check that token is valid or not .

I can't find anything about the token verification API from their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

After phone number authentication you get a Firebase ID token like you do for all other firebase authentication methods. You can get it by calling `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()`.

To verify it on your own server, you can send it to your server along with authenticated requests and use the Firebase admin SDK [`verifyIdToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) to verify that ID token and parse its underlying claims.